# Expresión regular en Validators.pattern

Tags: javascript, angular, validación

Tengo un campo password, que tienes que tener mínimo 12 caracteres, un carácter especial, una letra mayúscula y un número

```
password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$"), 
               Validators.minLength(12), Validators.required])],
```

Pero si no pongo ninguna letra mayúscula funciona.

```
<input class="form-control w100" formControlName="password" type="text" minlength="12" maxlength="50" required autofocus>
    <div *ngIf="form.controls['password'].invalid && (form.controls['password'].dirty || form.controls['password'].touched)" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" class="alert alert-danger pt10">
      <span class="p-inline-message p-inline-message-error" *ngIf="this.form.get('password')?.errors.required">Field is required</span>
      <span class="p-inline-message p-inline-message-error" *ngIf="this.form.get('password')?.errors.minlength">Must be at least 12 characters long.</span>
      <span class="p-inline-message p-inline-message-error" *ngIf="this.form.get('password')?.errors.pattern">
        Must be at least 1 special character.<br>
        Must be at least 1 number.<br>
        Must be at least 1 uppercase letter.
      </span>
    </div>
```

¿Hay alguan forma de independizar/especificar si el fallo es porque falta un número? Ahora el error esta generalizado por el pattern

Comment: ¿Has pensado en crear una función "manual" que compruebe los distintos requerimientos uno a uno? Las Regexp se pueden volver muy complejas y difíciles de mantener y no siempre son la solución ideal

Comment: He visto este ejemplo: CustomValidators.patternValidator(/\d/, { hasNumber: true }), pero me da error el CustomValidators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer algo como esto:

```js
import {AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn} from '@angular/forms';

export function getPasswordValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control:AbstractControl) : ValidationErrors | null => {

    const value = control.value;

    if (!value) {
      return null;
    }
    // falta definir caracteres especiales
    const hasSpecialChar = /[$%&]/.test(value);
    const hasUpperCase = /[A-Z]+/.test(value);
    const hasLowerCase = /[a-z]+/.test(value);
    const hasNumeric = /[0-9]+/.test(value);

    let result = null;
    if (!hasSpecialChar) {
      result = {missingSpecialChar: true};
    }
    if (!hasUpperCase) {
      result = (result || {}).missingUpperCase = true;
    }
    if (!hasLowerCase) {
      result = (result || {}).missingLowerCase = true;
    }
    if (!hasNumeric) {
      result = (result || {}).missingNumeric = true;
    }


    return result;
  }
}
```

y usarlo así:

```
password: ['', Validators.compose(getPasswordValidator(), 
           Validators.minLength(12), Validators.required])],
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, lo malo que ahi no tengo un mensaje personalizado que es lo que falta, ya que solo me informa si es válido o no, pensaba q existia algo en validator al igual como controla el min y max caracteres

Comment: Se puede hacer fácilmente, te actualizo