# Pattern no funciona correctamente

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy validando el campo de un password pero me da error cuando introduzco una password correcta. La contarseña tiene que tener mínimo 12 caracteres, una mayúscula, un número y un caracter especial

```
this.form= this.fb.group({
  password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$"), Validators.minLength(12), Validators.required])]
});
```

Y cuando pongo en el campo esta contraseña por ejm: Arcoiris@55!, me salta este if

```
<span *ngIf="this.form.get('password')?.errors.pattern">
```

Comment: intenta con `^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{12,}$` y quita a `Validators.minLength(12)`, me avisas.

Comment: me sigue saltando el if password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.pattern("^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{12,}$"), Validators.required])],

Comment: Y si colocas los Validators por separado fuera del compose, algo como `password: ['',[Validators.pattern(),Validators.minLength(12)]]`

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Expresión regular en Validators.pattern](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/554267/expresi%c3%b3n-regular-en-validators-pattern)

Comment: @PabloLozano me gustaria usar solo el pattern, sin llamar a otro método que verifique cada cosa

Comment: No vas a poder, a menos que me equivoque no es posible con una regex comprobar que hay cada conjunto de caracteres. Siempre requerirá un orden de aparición para cada grupo de caracteres porque una regex no hace "pasadas" por el texto

Comment: Me desdigo: se puede hacer con *look-ahead*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres solucionarlo sólo usando regexp, se puede hacer así:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{12,}$
```

Explicación:

```
^               Inicio de la línea
(?=.*[A-Z])     Tiene una mayúscula
(?=.*[!@#$&*])  Tiene uno de los caracteres ! @ # $ & * (puedes añadir más)
(?=.*[0-9])     Tiene un dígito
(?=.*[a-z])     Tiene una minúscula
.{12,}          Tiene al menos 12 caracteres
$               Fin de línea
```

Puedes probarla aquí: https://regex101.com/r/PCx0Aw/1

Personalmente se me hace más complejo mantener este código que usar la función que recomendé en el *casi-clon* de esta pregunta y no estoy seguro de si el rendimiento podría ser un problema, pero puesto que es debatible, queda fuera de tema.

Por otro lado, una validación usando esta regex tiene el problema añadido de que no te indica qué es exactamente lo que le falta a la contraseña.

Y para terminar, el uso de Validators.compose es innecesario, es una función que está por compatibilidad con las primeras versiones de Angular pero puede ser omitida:

```
 password: ['', Validators.compose([<validaciones>])]
```

es equivalente en las últimas versiones (cualquier versión posterior a 2016) a

```
 password: ['', [<validaciones>]]
```